# Changing wcf service from Http to https makes it unreachable

Tags: c#, wcf

I have had to change a wcf service I had running on console application to https due to an issue with "mixed content blocking" in firefox.

This is the config:

```
<services>
  <service name="ServiceHost.Services.BiometricCaptureService" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="CorsBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" contract="ServiceHost.IServices.IBiometricCaptureService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8502/biometrics/biometricscaptureservice.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CorsBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
      <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Default">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" type="ServiceHost.Utility.CORSBehaviorExtensionElement, ServiceHost, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Starting the service does not throw any errors with this configuration but I cannot hit on the endpoint any more.

The only error I could get was this: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Can anyone see any issues with this?

Comment: Try to add `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);` in your console application

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your service will find the encryption certificate.

You should have something like this:

```
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="mySvcBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="xxxxxx" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
      </serviceCredentials>
   </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This is a pretty decent step-by-step guide to setting up HTTPS on a WCF site. http://robbincremers.me/2011/12/27/wcf-transport-security-and-client-certificate-authentication-with-self-signed-certificates/

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid having to install a certificate and still be able to use HTTPS?

Comment: No ... you need a certificate. Just changing your security to "Transport" and your endpoint to "HTTPS" doesn't mean anything without the certificate and the programming to get the service to find the certificate. But even if you use HTTPS with a certificate, if the certificate is self-generated, Firefox will still complain about the cert not being published from an official CA (Cert authority). You might have to add the cert to the trusted list.